# Rails App With No Sign Up But Has Log In

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need some advice on a Rails app where I want to have signing up to be private (or not have one at all with users pre-registered in the seeds.rb file). In other words, I do not want random people off of the internet to be able to sign up. I know that I could easily not making a signup form and tweak my app accordingly, but the problem lies with the seeds.rb file containing sensitive information (i.e., passwords). The passwords need to somehow be encrypted. Any advice would help. Thanks.

Comment: Would you be willing to give people a randomly generated pw that needs to be reset upon login?

Comment: Yes, that would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1. Disable sign up and do it manually using an admin user (thinking about [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) gem).
2. Register that users at DB (without rails' knowledge). I don't know what DB you're using, but imagine you're using postgreSQL (for instance). Go to your DB and manually insert the users on DB using some kind of user interface (command-line or graphic/visual)
3. Use environment variables at deployment that contain passwords.
4. Give them a default password and make them change password once they log in.
5. ... there are more options, but you need to be explicit about what you want to achieve. Do you want to start with X users and don't add more? Do you want to start with X users and be able to expand to more users?

Comment: I want to start with X users and be able to expand to more users and give them a default password and make them change password once they log in.

Comment: So option 1 or 2 and then 3